# React native module Linking issue of packages

Tags: react-native, react-native-modules

I have created a native-module named MyNativeModule. in which i have added a package named `react-native-scrypt` as a dependency. When i install MyNativeModule in MyApp then while using the package internally inside MyNativeModule using some function i get error due to `react-native-scrypt` not have been linked to my project.

What should i do in MyNativeModule, which links all the native modules(packages) installed in MyNativeModule to the application.

PS. I do not want to install same packages used in MyNativeModule or mention them anywhere.